# Cypress timeout values not working when set

Tags: cypress

```
[2] Start: 18/03/2022, 17:10:16
[2]       1) Loading spinner should display first
[2] 
[2]   0 passing (7s)
[2]   1 failing
[2] 
[2]   1) Common
[2]        Page loading
[2]          Loading spinner should display first:
[2] 
[2]       AssertionError: Expected <div.ui.active.transition.visible.inverted.dimmer> not to exist in the DOM, but it was continuously found.
[2]       + expected - actual
[2] 
[2] 
[2]       at Context.eval (https://localhost:9090/__cypress/tests?p=integration/common.cypress.js:27567:12)
[2] 
[2] 
[2] 
[2] After Each: 18/03/2022, 17:10:22
```

So from the `Start` to the `After Each` is 6 seconds. However, I've set the timeout value well above 6 seconds:

```
  describe('Page loading', () => {
    it('Loading spinner should display first', () => {
      let sendResponse;
      const trigger = new Promise(resolve => {
        sendResponse = resolve;
      });

      cy.intercept(
        {
          method: 'GET',
          url: '/databases?Namespace=self',
          hostname: 'localhost',
        },
        request => {
          return trigger.then(() => {
            request.reply();
          });
        }
      );

      cy.visit('https://localhost:9090');
      log('Start: ' + new Date(Date.now()).toLocaleString());
      cy.getByTestId('loader-spinner', { timeout: 1000000000 })
        .should('be.visible', { timeout: 1000000000 })
        .then(() => {
          sendResponse();
          cy.getByTestId('loader-spinner', { timeout: 1000000000 }).should('not.exist', {
            timeout: 1000000000,
          }); // <--- second should
        });
    });
```

I don't understand why the second `should` is not waiting.

Comment: [`.should()`](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/should#Syntax). That might be the issue. The [`timeout`](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/core-concepts/retry-ability#Timeouts) option should remain on the command prior to the `.should()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was the testing library I was using: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58857483/1137669

From that answer, the `getByTestId` immediately fails, what I should have been using was `get`.

Comment: Or findBy..., as noted [in the docs](https://testing-library.com/docs/cypress-testing-library/intro/#usage).

Comment: https://testing-library.com/docs/queries/about#types-of-queries

Answer (score 0):

You can see in the [docs](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/configuration#Timeouts), there're currently these timeouts you can set up:

1. default command timeout
2. exec timeout
3. task timeout
4. page load timeout
5. request timeout
6. response timeout

And in your test, you can use "defaultCommandTimeout" to change default timeout

ex:
cypress.json

```
{
  "defaultCommandTimeout": 5000
}
```

you can just apply this configuration in a single test.

```
it('slow test', { defaultCommandTimeout: 5000 },  () => {

  // will wait 5 seconds for element to appear in dom
  cy.get('slowElement')

})
```

[Cypress.config() documentation](https://docs.cypress.io/api/cypress-api/config#No-Arguments)